# Incorrect Response - Reachability For WWAN

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, reachability, wwan

While checking for reachability(network availability) of an iPAD 3 WiFi+Cellular, I ran into across a weird issue that happened in the below mentioned scenario.

- To check network availability I have used [Apple sample code for
  reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html).
- The following code was implemented to check availability of WiFi or WWAN.

`

```
- (BOOL)networkCheck
 {
    Reachability *wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Not Connected");    
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WiFi");       
            return true;
            break;
        } 
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

`

- In a scenario when there was NO SIM in the iPAD & also there was
  No-WiFi connection, the above method executes ReachableViaWWAN case,
  which seems **totally incorrect** as there is NO SIM or any other
  WWAN network available.

To Overcome this issue a workaround (or should I say a hack) was suggested & implemented as follows: 
Send a request to a reliable host & check for its response.

```
case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
        NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        if (responseData != nil)
        {
            return true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }

    }
```

I have a couple of queries:

1. This may sound offbeat, but is it something wrong with the hardware
   or iOS that it's ReachableViaWWAN even when NO SIM is present in the
   device?
2. Is there a better solution (than the workaround mentioned above) for the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a bug in your code but you can try using [this](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) to check the connection.
from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk).

and for check the connectivity  you can create a method like this:

```
 -(BOOL)connected
  {
     Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
     NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
     return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
 }
```

and wherever you want to check the connection just

```
if (![self connected]) {
//THERE IS NO WWAN OR WIFI connection
}else{
// connected. 
}
```

It works fine for me.