# iOS Reachability is not detecting "No Service" in the device as "NotReachable"

Tags: ios, reachability, connectivity, cellular-network

I'm using the `Reachability` class provided by Apple and I'm listening for the `reachabilityChanged:` notification:

```
- (void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
   Reachability *reach = [notification object];

   if ([reach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]) {
       NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

       if ((status == ReachableViaWiFi) || (status == ReachableViaWWAN)) {
          // Some operations here
       }
   }
}
```

When I set flight mode or disable WiFi and cellular data in settings, I get a "NotReachable" status in `reachabilityChanged:`, but when my device seems to just lose the connectivity temporarily for whatever reason (having communications enabled in settings), the "NotReachable" status seems to not being detected.

I've done some tests with a jammer, and when the device goes to "No Service" in the status bar and `reachabilityChanged:` is called, I've seen that the `NetworkStatus` is "ReachableViaWWAN" instead of "NotReachable" as I expected.

I need to detect such "No Service" status in the device, how could I?

Comment: are you plugged in via usb to your computer? Is it sharing the network connection?

Comment: @Fogmeister it is plugged in to see logs in Xcode, but it only has cellular data enabled

Comment: yes. But if your computer is sharing it's Internet connection via usb then the phone will still have connection.

Comment: @Fogmeister I disconnected the device from the computer and I'm still getting a "ReachableViaWWAN" status when the device has "No Service"...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17495221/1391672). This worked for me:

```
- (BOOL)networkCheck
{
    Reachability *wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];

    switch (netStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Not Connected");    
            return false;
            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WiFi");       
            return true;
            break;
        } 
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
            return true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return false;
 }
```

And then in the ReachableViaWWAN case:

```
case ReachableViaWWAN:
{
    NSLog(@"%@",@"NETWORKCHECK: Connected Via WWAN");
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]] returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    if (responseData != nil)
    {
        return true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        break;
    }

}
```